# How to restrict an Oracle apex item to numeric/character values

Tags: sql, oracle, check-constraints

I have a **TEXT** item field - order number, where user can enter his details.

- When a user enters order number starting with 1, it should allow only numeric values.
- When a user enters order number starting with L, it should accept both numeric and alphabets.

How can I do it in Oracle Apex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a **CHECK** constraint on the column to allow:

- values with only digits when starting with '1'
- values as it is when starting with 'L'

**Check constraint** would be:

```
CHECK
(
  CASE
  WHEN SUBSTR(text,1,1) ='1' THEN
    REGEXP_substr(text, '^[[:digit:]]+$')
  WHEN SUBSTR(text,1,1) ='L' THEN
    text
  END IS NOT NULL)
```

Let's look at a test case:

**Setup**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(text VARCHAR2(30));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT t_chk CHECK
  2  (
  3    CASE
  4    WHEN SUBSTR(text,1,1) ='1' THEN
  5      REGEXP_substr(text, '^[[:digit:]]+$')
  6    WHEN SUBSTR(text,1,1) ='L' THEN
  7      text
  8    END IS NOT NULL);

Table altered.

SQL>
```

**Test**

```
SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES('123');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES('1a');
INSERT INTO t VALUES('1a')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (LALIT.T_CHK) violated


SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES('L12A');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES('A12A');
INSERT INTO t VALUES('A12A')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (LALIT.T_CHK) violated


SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

TEXT
------------------------------
123
L12A

SQL>
```

So, it **only allowed** values `'123'` and `'L12A'`. And it **didn't allow** values `'1a'` and `'A12A'`.
Works perfectly!

Comment: Thanks a lot:) Logic Worked:)

Comment: I saw that question, however, I don't work with reports. So, I am afraid I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

For a solution that checks when the APEX page is submitted, and gives a nice error message on the field in error, you can create a "Validation" for the field, example here validates an email address (with an incorrect REGEX - but fairly correct).  It uses a PL/SQL function returning a  Boolean.

Function:

```
begin
  return regexp_count(:P811_EMAIL_ADDRESS, '^[-_A-Z0-9.]+@([A-Z]+\.)?[A-Z]+\.COM$') >= 1;
end;
```

APEX Application:

[image: APEX example]